# Как правильно сделать git checkout на ветку

Tags: git

Сделал `git clone` с репо, моя ветка - `master`. Мне нужно переключится на другую ветку c удаленного репо, которой нет локально - `test-branch`. Если с мастера создаю ветку и тяну туда, тогда появляются конфликты и нужно все это мержить. А мне мержить не нужно, нужно просто переключится на удаленную ветку без изменений с мастера.

Вот когда я делаю так

1. `git clone remote`
2. `git checkout test-branch`
3. `git pull origin test-branch`

У меня сливается мастер и удаленная ветка `test-branch`, чего мне не нужно. Возможно есть способ для переключения на удаленную ветку без слияния ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во первых, можно сразу клонировать нужную ветку

```
git clone -b <branch> <remote_repo>
```

В вашем случае, можно создать локальную ветку во время checkout:

```
git checkout -b feat_branch origin/feat_branch
```

Либо, без непосредственного переключения:

```
git branch feat_branch origin/feat_branch
```

Comment: Может быть ещё стоит упомянуть, что команде **git checkout** можно передать имя удалённой ветки без параметра `-b`, и про режим отсоединённой головы

Comment: Потом всё равно нужно будет `git checkout -b new_branch`. К тому же я не уверен, будет ли отслеживать родительскую ветку) Там от конфигов зависит.

Answer (score 1):

После того как склонировали репозиторий делаете `git fetch`, потом `git checkout test-branch`